# iTunes wants to download an update before it restores my iPad. Way around this?

Tags: itunes

I would let iTunes download the iOS 9.3.4 update, but it's already been downloaded & installed. And when iTunes tries to download the update again, it can't. It tries for several minutes, then stops the entire process--and I don't get my Restore.

I've deleted .plist files associated with iTunes and it hasn't helped. Is there any way to restore my iPad without launching this futile attempt at a download?

iMac mid-2010 running El Capitan 10.11.5, iTunes 12.4.3.1

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Figured this out. Logged out of iTunes store, logged back in with second account. It demanded to download the update once, I assented, it failed, and it finally abandoned the idea. iPad restored.